# how to auto redirect to another page when a war in tomcat stop

Tags: apache, tomcat, war, web-deployment

My tomcat contains a war which I deployed. And the apache web server is running in front of my tomcat. And I have just one server.

I hope that users visiting the web could have the below experience:

1. When the war is stopped or in the period of re-deploying, users will see another page which tells users that the system is in maintenance.
2. When the war is running again, users will see the normal pages in the war.

I hope all the transform mechanism is automatically, no need people's handwork.

How or what should I config tomcat /apache web server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using ErrorDocument directive. This directive can be global, at virtual or directory level. Choose as per your requirement

e.g

```
ErrorDocument 500 "Server down"
ErrorDocument 501 "Server down"
ErrorDocument 502 "Server down"
```

You can also return static page contains some error message and help text or you can use dynamic resource to show more information

Please see apache document [Custom errors](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html)

For nginx it is like below

```
error_page 502 =200 /false.html;

location /false.html {
}
```

where false.html can be a static resource or a dynamic proxy. Please note, in nginx we can change the response code also as done in above example. I am not sure if we can do that in Apache HTTPD